# Calculate distance between two locations using google map in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I just want to calculate distance between two location .
In which user can enter both the location's addresses, and from that addresses I want to calculate the distance between them.

Is it possible to calculate distance from CLLocation using these addresses ?

Answer (score 7):

First you need to geocode the address to latitude/longitude, then you can use the CLLocation framework to calculate the distance.
To geocode the adress, you could use this [forward geocoding API](http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/).

```
// get CLLocation fot both addresses
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:address.latitude longitude:address.longitude];

// calculate distance between them
CLLocationDistance distance = [firstLocation distanceFromLocation:secondLocation];
```