# Xcode for distance between two locations in google maps

Tags: xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate distance between two locations using google map in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551610/calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-google-map-in-iphone)

I just want to complete xcode for calculate distance between two location . In which user can enter both the location's addresses, and from that addresses I want to calculate the distance between them b,coz am new to xcode.
      Please send a link/code as soon as possible
Thank you

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE - you probably mean C or Objective-C code, I imagine ?

Answer (score 1):

From addresses you have to take the latitude and longitudes.
like this

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", theAddress];
NSString *locationString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] autorelease];
NSArray *splitArray = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]] autorelease];

if([splitArray count]!=0)
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = [[splitArray objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    region.center.longitude = [[splitArray objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01; // Add a little extra space on the sides
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01; // Add a little extra space on the sides
    region = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    CLLocation *firstLocation= [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[[splitArray objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue] longitude:[[splitArray objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue]];
```

//in the sameway for secondlocation also

CLLocationDistance distance = [firstLocation distanceFromLocation:secondLocation];