# How can I see the driver current location(while driving) on Google Maps in center of the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, mapkit

Currently I am working on an app similar to Uber app for iOS devices.

For that purpose I used Google Map SDK

my query is: 
**While driver drives he needs to see his current location with poly line on center of the map always, distance & total time travelled**

Here I found one sample image with MKMapKit code:[Image URL link](http://www.johnmullins.co/images/location_tracker/fun2.gif) and [Sample code url](http://www.johnmullins.co/blog/2014/08/14/location-tracker-with-maps/)

I am also looking same code for `Google Map` with custom image(Car symbol).

How can I solve this issue? please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're the driver, you can use [Geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation) to detect your current location.

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967496/google-maps-ios-sdk-getting-current-location-of-user), you have to retrieve the position by using `CLLocationManager`.

> First, add the `CoreLocation.framework` to your project :
>
> - Go in `Project Navigator`
> - Select your project
> - Click on the tab `Build Phases`
> - Add the `CoreLocation.framework` in the `Link Binary with Libraries`
>
> Then all you need to do is to follow the basic example of [Apple
>   documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1).
>
> - Create a `CLLocationManager` probably in your `ViewDidLoad`:
>
>   ```
>   if (nil == locationManager)
>       locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
>
>   locationManager.delegate = self;
>   //Configure Accuracy depending on your needs, default is kCLLocationAccuracyBest
>   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
>
>   // Set a movement threshold for new events.
>   locationManager.distanceFilter = 500; // meters
>
>   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
>   ```
>
> With the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` every time the position is
>   updated, you can update the user position on your `Google Maps` :
>
> ```
> - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
>       didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
>     // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power.
>    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
>    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
>    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
>    if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0) {
>       // Update your marker on your map using location.coordinate.latitude
>       //and location.coordinate.longitude); 
>    }
> }
> ```

It will also work if you use the native `MapKit.framework`. You need to add `yourMapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;` and the framework will do everything. (Except center the map on you position).

Follow the steps from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start). If you want to update the map to follow your position, you can copy Google example `MyLocationViewController.m` that is included in the framework directory. They just add a observer on the `myLocation` property to update the camera properties.

To get the total distance travelled, check this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551610/calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-google-map-in-iphone). It states that you need to geocode the address to latitude/longitude, then you can use the `CLLocation` framework to calculate the distance.

> To geocode the adress, you could use this [forward geocoding
>   API](http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/).
>
> ```
> // get CLLocation fot both addresses
> CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:address.latitude longitude:address.longitude];
>
> // calculate distance between them
> CLLocationDistance distance = [firstLocation distanceFromLocation:secondLocation];
> ```

You can also check this [related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578116/what-is-proper-way-to-get-eta-estimated-time-arrival-from-any-location-to-my-c).

Hope this helps!